# How can I force a view to use a specific index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How can I force a view to use a specific index?

I am getting the below warning message when I try to force use index :

> Warning: Index hints supplied for view 'BANK.CUSTOMER_ORDER_VIEW' will be ignored.

Below is my query:

```
DECLARE  @VALUE_DATE_START DATE = '20181001',
         @VALUE_DATE_END DATE  = '20181025'

SELECT * 
FROM BANK.CUSTOMER_ORDER_VIEW WITH(INDEX(IX_ValueDate))
WHERE VALUE_DATE BETWEEN @VALUE_DATE_START AND @VALUE_DATE_END
```

`IX_ValueDate` is the index of a table that is used in `BANK.CUSTOMER_ORDER_VIEW`.

Comment: You have tried and it doesn't work.  Query hints go on the outermost query.  In general, you can trust the optimizer to do the right thing.

Comment: Views in SQL are like macros in many other languages. Whichever queries they're used in, the view definition is "expanded" into the query and then the query as a whole (both the bits from inside any views and the bits explicitly written based on views) is optimized as one thing.

Comment: Did you try FORCESEEK hint?

Comment: If you find the optimizer isn't using an (obvious) index on `value_date`, first verify that its row estimates are correct and update statistics if they're not. Also consider `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR)` if you find it's not using the correct values for the estimation. Forcing an index should always be considered a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, you've solved my problem. OPTION(RECOMPILE) is the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to take cares of writing the hints: the query/table hints are for recommendation only, the optimizer may ignore them as in your case. 
This point is not well documented [but mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017) somewhere, for example

> When an index hint referring to multiple indexes is used on the fact
>   table in a star join, the optimizer ignores the index hint and returns
>   a warning message.

On other hand, your query is a typical example when `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is required because of declared variables: once generated and cached plan for the narrow period is not suitable for a large period etc.